# Ross: 8.9 "For all but finitely many..."

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding this problem.

*Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence that converges. 
A: Show that if $s_n \geq a$ for all but finitely many $n,$ then $\lim s_n \geq a$.*

In this case does "for all but finitely many" mean that only some terms of the sequence are greater than a? This is how I interpreted it and this is my proof:

Proof

Suppose $s_n \geq a$ for finitely many n, let $s=\lim s_n $. Then there exists an N such that $n>N$  implies

$$|s_n - s| < a -s$$

Which implies

$$|s_n|< a \Rightarrow s_n<a $$

Which holds since finitely many terms are bounded below by a, so infinitely many terms are bounded above by a.

Is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: `all but` means "all ***except***". In the given context, it translates to "$\exists N$ such that $s_n \ge a$ for $\forall n \ge N$".

Comment: In this case "for all but finitely many $n$" means that only some finite number of terms of the sequence are less than a.

Comment: Saying "A implies B, and B holds" is not a valid proof of A.

Answer (score 0):

It means only finitely many terms are smaller than $a$, the rest of them are bigger than $a$.

So you should correct your proof as :

"Suppose $s_n \color{red}< a$ for finitely many $n$, then there exists an $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $s_n \geq a$."

Suppose $s< a$, try to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I've been looking at proofs using contradiction but I want to be able to prove this another way.

This is my next attempt, please correct me if I'm wrong:

***Proof***

Suppose $(s_n)$ converges and $s_n \geq a$ for all but finitely many $n.$ Let $s=\lim s_n$.

There exists an N such that n>N implies

$$|s_n -s | < s \Rightarrow |s_n|<2s $$

In particular for all n>N

$$s_n < 2s $$

Now since $a \leq s_n$ for all but finitely many $n,$ and since $s_n <2s$ for all $n>N,$ then $a \leq 2s$ which implies $a \leq s$.

Comment: $a \leq 2s $ doesn't imply $a \leq s$. It doesn't seem to me to be much use invoking that $s_n$ is less than $s$ away from $s$ for large enough $n$. Your sequence converges, which means that $s_n$ is less than $\epsilon$ away from $s$ for large enough $n$, *for as small an $\epsilon$ as you like*.

Comment: `|s_n-s| < s` Certainly not if `s` happens to be negative.